# Sent Bitcoin Payment Frozen?

Tags: transactions

I sent a payment from Coinbase to someone and they see the transaction but the funds are not depositing into there wallet it has been 4 days.  What is going on please help?

Hash
3e94ad695a30a94ab38f66ccb4bbc1b7fc70d9990ed6b6881d923af87cba8b96

Answer (score 1):

According to [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/3e94ad695a30a94ab38f66ccb4bbc1b7fc70d9990ed6b6881d923af87cba8b96), not only has the recipient received the funds, but they appear to have already spent them again.

Comment: Really?  They are telling me they see the transaction but the funds are not going into there wallet?  Sorry this is my first transaction.  :/

Comment: Yes. It has already been sent to `154CiogqQQrPFfAwc8PbndvA4dzVpN26VN`, mainly. Click on the address `1G58qQGPnxmQR5iXqX9oqQUQVnUWot5Z9q` which is the address you sent  0.661135 BTC to. You then see the transactions it has been involved in. Green arrows mean that that address gained money, red arrows mean that that address lost money in the transaction. There  are 2: The lower one is the one via which you sent money to it and the upper one is the one which already took that money (and a lot more money from many different addresses) and sent it to `154CiogqQQrPFfAwc8PbndvA4dzVpN26VN` (mainly).