# Sent btc from coinbase, says confirmed but recipient says they’ve not received?

Tags: transactions

I sent btc out of my coinbase account 11 days ago now (£229.02 i was purchasing an item), everything says confirmed on my end and the transaction has had over 1000 confirmation now. So I’m confused this is my first time using my coinbase account.

When I paste the recipients address in block chain explorer I can’t see the money I sent, but when I click the link that opens the block chain explorer from coinbase it’s shows as confirmed.so I don’t know…

& yes the address is right I checked multiple times.

The transaction hash id: 5655ffd3dfd6e6ecf4ec456f895ab44437507ae1173f2897cd990933a81dd8a5

Recipient address: bc1qe4m5y20wyrra8daezg50a2xmqaf9k6hsnhgjgv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, transaction 5655ffd3dfd6e6ecf4ec456f895ab44437507ae1173f2897cd990933a81dd8a5 has over a thousand confirmations as shown on [a blockchain explorer](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/5655ffd3dfd6e6ecf4ec456f895ab44437507ae1173f2897cd990933a81dd8a5)

> TRANSACTION IDENTIFIER:
> 5655ffd3dfd6e6ecf4ec456f895ab44437507ae1173f2897cd990933a81dd8a5
> TRANSACTION TIMESTAMP: 2023-07-20 13:18 (UTC)
> CONFIRMED TRANSACTION:
> Included in block: #799532 on the Bitcoin blockchain
>
> SENDERS (INPUTS):
>
> | SENDER | VALUE (BTC) | VALUE (USD) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 38Nvm7Swc5fqvm9N68iFET3T5Rz2dfFegt | 0.52895463 | 15,823.68 |
>
> TOTAL: 0.52895463 BTC   15,823.68 USD
>
> RECIPIENTS (OUTPUTS):
>
> | N | RECIPIENT | VALUE (BTC) | VALUE (USD) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 14QckVSBsgZbpX7Pw3ASx8juJXhRzedVkE | 0.00082803 | 24.77 |
> | 1 | bc1qx69fs6sv4j732rqax5sawn5t0uy8g2sse723l4 | 0.00210436 | 62.95 |
> | 2 | bc1q3q4s3jps4lmwdy46pvykemgv008n9k26lue2g4 | 0.14337767 | 4,289.14 |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 21 | bc1qntsec6pugqs9gf2qt4576aw9gl2dgz0nr0ttjs | 0.00061880 | 18.51 |
> | 22 | **bc1qe4m5y20wyrra8daezg50a2xmqaf9k6hsnhgjgv** | 0.00974005 | 291.37 |
> | 23 | bc1qd9pqmnmh33k2w72se8wt5gs5w86nmjalp2efx2 | 0.01583112 | 473.59 |
>
> MINER FEE: 0.00016934 5.07
> TOTAL: 0.52895463 BTC   15,818.61 USD

There are 24 recipients because coinbase has batched together transactions from several of its customers.

One of those recipients is address bc1qe4m5y20wyrra8daezg50a2xmqaf9k6hsnhgjgv which can be seen at [a blockchain explorer](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1qe4m5y20wyrra8daezg50a2xmqaf9k6hsnhgjgv) as having received 0.00974005BTC in that transaction.

[image: explorer address total]
[image: explorer address transaction]

So the recipient has absolutely definitely received the money. They have control over it, not anyone else.

See

- [Bitcoin sent, recipient claiming not received](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/92058/13866)
- [I sent Bitcoin to an address but the recipient hasn't yet received it](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/93145/13866)
- [Sent BTC from Coinbase, blockchain explorer says Confirmed. Is recipient lying or could something else be the issue?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91959/13866)
- [My issue is same as many others sent BTC but funds were not received](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/117667/13866)
- [Sent Bitcoin Payment Frozen?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/52465/13866)
- [about a stuck bitcoin transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/59460/13866)
- [Sending Bitcoin to a wallet but user has not received](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/93874/13866)

[etc etc](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=recipient+not+received)

Comment: Thank you , manège to get my £ back they was trying to scam me. But I provided too much proof for them to deny thanks to you.